# Using JDBC resource and servlet from Netbeans

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, jdbc, netbeans

I'm new to Java EE, especially with connection pools (which I don't even begin to understand correctly). I tried to make a basic JDBC Resource with Netbeans, with New >> JDBC Resource. It created the following **glassfish-resources.xml**:

```
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/myDB" object-type="user" pool-name="miConnectionPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="miConnectionPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebasbd?relaxAutoCommit=&quot;true&quot;"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="root"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

After this, I reused an old servlet, "MiServlet", which is in the default package. This servlet used to work some time ago with the typical beginning practises with servlets, but now it just won't send any response. I've got it configured in the web.xml so it gets called at the url pattern "localhost/myProject/index", but nothing gets shown.

Here you have the XML config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MiServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

(...)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the servlet processRequest method right now. I highlighted the parts where I'm trying to use my newly created JDBC resource (I seriously have no idea if I'm doing wrong or not!):

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            **// Context creation
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context webContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

            DataSource ds = (DataSource) webContext.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
            Connection dbCon = ds.getConnection();**
            PreparedStatement ps = dbCon.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM person");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            String res = "BEGINNING\n";
            while(rs.next()){
                res += rs.getString(1)+"\n";
            }

            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
                out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
                out.println("<html>");
                out.println("<head>");
                out.println("<title>Servlet MiServlet</title>");
                out.println("</head>");
                out.println("<body>");
                out.println("<h1>Servlet MiServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
                out.println("<p>"+res+"</p>");
                out.println("</body>");
                out.println("</html>");
            }
        }   catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MiServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MiServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

This simple test *should* show up all the person's first column from my WAMP MySQL server in this same computer, using the JDBC resource I previously created with the NetBeans wizard. But all I get, is this empty HTML page, with not even the static content written in the servlet (which shows that it's not even getting called):

I call at

> https://localhost:8181/PruebasJ2EE-war/index

... and I get:

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" title="Ajustar líneas largas">
</head>
<body>
<pre></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit:

Now with M-Mariscal answer's code, it manages to connect, but it still can't find any table or schema. If I point the query to pruebasbd.persona:

> Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: El esquema
>   'PRUEBASBD' no existe.
>   (Schema PRUEBASBD does not exist)

if I point it to the table "persona" (since I already selected that schema in the glassfish-resources.xml as previously shown):

> Grave:   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: La tabla/vista 'PERSONA' no
>   existe.
>   (Table/view PERSONA does not exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm learning Java EE right now! and I'm doing the ContextConfiguration on method 'init', hope my exercise be helpful 'colega', I don't know if I'm helping you but is the best that I can do for you, if you need more code just ask for! ;)

```
public class JdbcServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private DataSource pool;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {        
        Context env = null;
        try {
            env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            pool = (DataSource) env.lookup("sample");   //nombre en web.xml
            if (pool == null) {
                throw new ServletException("No se encontró el DataSource");
            }
        }   catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }          

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Connection conexion = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<h1>Lista de amigos</h1>");
            try {                
                conexion = pool.getConnection();
                Statement statement = conexion.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM personas";
                ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                if (res.next()) {                                            
                    do {
                       out.println("<p>Nombre: "+res.getString("nombre")+
                               "<br/>Edad:"+res.getInt("edad")+"</p>");
                    } while (res.next());
                } else {
                    out.println("<p>No hay amigos dados de alta</p>");
                }   
                out.println("<a href='index.html'>Volver al inicio</a>");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conexion != null && !conexion.isClosed())
                        conexion.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
        String edad = request.getParameter("edad");

        if (nombre != null && edad != null) {
            Connection conexion = null;
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
                int numEdad = Integer.parseInt(edad);
                String sql = "INSERT INTO personas VALUES('"+nombre+"',"+numEdad+")";
                conexion = pool.getConnection();
                statement = conexion.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate(sql);                
                doGet(request, response);
            } catch (NumberFormatException | SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (conexion != null && !conexion.isClosed())
                        conexion.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it's still not working :(, check this exception:  "Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[JdbcServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet JdbcServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at JdbcServlet.doGet(JdbcServlet.java:51)" It seems that the "pool" object isn't initializing at the "init" method.

Comment: Better post your exception on your question please ;)

Comment: I managed to get it working! But it still throws errors like "Table PERSONA" not found (yes, my table's name is "persona", checked it). It neither works if I put the db schema "pruebasbd" before. Let me update the question.

Comment: I have another tutorial of how to set connection pool (I made a look at it and seems very explicit) https://dzone.com/articles/nb-class-glassfish-mysql-jdbc | it's really powerful too! https://christmo99.wordpress.com/2008/04/09/pool-connection/

Comment: Have you checked my last error? It's strange that it connects but can't find anything, isn't it?

Comment: I'm checking, don't worry man ;) but I need more practices about it to be helpful jeje

Comment: Hey man! make a look at names of you "db", "schema", your table is "person", and you tried "persona", Am I wrong? it's case sensitive as you know

Comment: No, no! Check this other question, which is more specific for this error. Your answer is accepted!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862994/unable-to-find-table-in-a-jdbc-resource