# Unable to find table in a working JDBC resource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish

I've got the following resource, which I uploaded into my `Glassfish` server:

**glassfish-resources.xml**

```
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/nuevaConexion" object-type="user" pool-name="nuevaConexionPool">
    <description/>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="nuevaConexionPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pruebasbd?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value=""/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

This server is in a WAMP server I'm running on this same machine. When I ping it from the Glassfish server, it works correctly.

Then, I declare this server in my Web.xml resource references, as:

> jdbc/nuevaConexion

I create a servlet mapped to the "/jdbc" route, just for testing purposes. This servlet initiates this way:

**MyServlet.java**

```
  private DataSource pool;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {        
        Context env = null;
        try {
            Logger.getLogger("Inicializando...");
            env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
            pool = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/nuevaConexion");   //nombre en web.xml
            if (pool == null) {
                throw new ServletException("No se encontró el DataSource");
            }
        }   catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JdbcServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Pretty straightforward. Ok, then, I make use of this calling to my table "persona", which is in the schema that was defined in the resource xml I shouwed you before. This is the code:

```
 conexion = pool.getConnection();
                Statement statement = conexion.createStatement();
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM persona";
                ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Somehow, it just won't find the table "PERSONA":

> Grave: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: La tabla/vista 'PERSONA' no
>   existe. (Table/view PERSONA does not exist)

If I point to "pruebasbd.persona" it doesn't work either:

> Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException:  El esquema
>   'PRUEBASBD' no existe. (Schema PRUEBASBD does not exist)

You can see here that my DB exists:

[image]

Why can't it find my table? The connection is working, but it just won't find anything in there.

Comment: Hey mate! make a look at this website: https://stuetzpunkt.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/create-jdbc-resources-on-glassfish-4-with-glassfish-resources-xml/ I'm still here helping you ;) check the line      **   <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby:....;create=true"/>**

Comment: I still don't know what's wrong :/

Comment: Can you post your glassfish-web.xml & web.xml please? My mate is helping you too, he understands it

Comment: Have you tried to set on <jdbc-connection-pool>
**javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource** instead of **javax.sql.DataSource**??

Comment: Gotta retake this tomorrow, now I'm out of the office and don't have access to my config! But tomorrow will test this. Thank you mate :) !

Comment: Ok mate! hope to help you 1% at least! You catched me learning this heavy stuff right now and just tried to give you some working code ;)

Comment: Hey, your fix just worked! I've set in the web.xml my resource as javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource and now it's properly getting the results! Thank you mate!